# Chrome Extension Breaks HTTPS

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, https

I've written a simple Chrome extension that is configured with the staff members id and a field name within that page to trigger focus on. ie: `id` and `fieldName`

When the user clicks within that field ajax is used to send the users ID to a local web server.

```
$('[name=' + fieldName + ']').focus(function () {
    console.log ( "FOCUS - "  + id + ' ' + fieldName)
    $.ajax({ url : 'https://LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS/staff.php?staffID=' + id });
});
```

The extension can be run on ANY hosted web page, `LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS` is the internal IP Address of our local web server which the users PC can also reach.

No data from the site is being sent from the page, only a values from the extension configuration.

The above works fine. However...

I load a HTTPS site and Chrome reports it as secure.

I click within the relevant field and the staffID is sent to our local webserver.  However the web site now reports as insecure.

Is there anything I can do to stop that happening ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Declare an [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages):

   ```js
   "background": {
       "scripts": ["jquery.js", "eventPage.js"],
       "persistent": false
   },
   ```
2. From your content script send the id in a message to the event page:

   ```js
   $('[name=' + fieldName + ']').focus(() => chrome.runtime.sendMessage({id}));
   ```
3. The event page does the AJAX request:

   ```js
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
       $.ajax({url : 'https://LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS/staff.php?staffID=' + msg.id});
   });
   ```

Optionally, you can send AJAX request results back to the content script asynchronously:

- content script:

  ```js
  $('[name=' + fieldName + ']').focus(() => {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({id}, status => console.log(status))
  });
  ```
- event page:

  ```js
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
      $.ajax({
          url : 'https://LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS/staff.php?staffID=' + msg.id,
          complete: xhr => sendResponse(xhr.status),
      });
      return true; // leave the channel open for sendResponse
  });
  ```

Comment: Thanks I will test this as soon as possible

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking at setting this up. I currently run a second ajax when I `focusout` will it be possible to do that ?

Comment: Of course: simply cook the entire url in the content script and send it in a message.